# How to use function return type as variable type?

Tags: typescript

```
function f() {
  return {
    some: string,
    very: number,
    complicated: {...},
    type_: boolean
  }
}

someArray: <the type that's returned from f>[] = []
```

Can I somehow get the type returned from `f` without declaring it directly? So not that:

```
type TypeThatsReturnedFromf = {...}

function f(): TypeThatsReturnedFromf {...}

someArray: TypeThatsReturnedFromf[] = []
```

Comment: [`ReturnType<typeof f>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript's `ReturnType<>`:

```
let someArray: ReturnType<typeof f>[] = [
  {
    some: '' // Auto-completion works
  }
];
```